# Autosuggestion combobox with retrieve the values from mysql database

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

Am using the following java program for Autosuggestion combobox with retrieve the values from mysql database.the Auto Suggestion working properly.If i type 'A' in the combobox means the list will show the all names starting with 'A'.i add the label in that form.If i select the one name in combo box means the corresponding Id will display in the Label. My problem is i have the four names with starting 'A' in my Sql database table,if I select that 'A' starting name that will show correct Id.but I clear the combobox text column and type 'B' means it show the all name starting with 'B' but it I click the "B" started name it can't display the correct ID,It display the ID for 'A' starting name.because I get the Id using getSelectedIndex().how to get the correct ID for all names in auto suggest combobox?

```
package combo;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class comboauto extends javax.swing.JFrame {
         Vector  v=new Vector();
         Vector v1=new Vector();
         Statement TmpSqlStmnt;
         ResultSet TmpSqlRs;
         Connection con;
         int CateId;
         JTextField Txt01;

    public comboauto() {
        initComponents();
    }
   public void AutoSuggest() {
               Txt01=(JTextField)Cbx01.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
               Txt01.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
                {
                 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                 {
                   public void run() {
                   String text =Txt01.getText().toUpperCase();
                   if(text.length()==0)
                             {
                                Cbx01.hidePopup();
                                setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(v1), "");
                             }
                             else{
                                DefaultComboBoxModel m = getSuggestedModel(v1, text);
                               if(m.getSize()==0 ) {
                               Cbx01.hidePopup();
                                 }
                                else{
                                          setModel(m, text);
                                         Cbx01.showPopup();
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                          });

                    }
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
                 {
                    String text = Txt01.getText();
                    int code = e.getKeyCode();
                    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    if(!v1.contains(text)) {
                    v1.addElement(text);
                   // setModel(getSuggestedModel(v1, text), text);
            }
                    hide_flag = true;
        }else if(code==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
         hide_flag = true;
        }else if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++) {
                String str = (String) v1.elementAt(i);
                if(str.startsWith(text))
                {
       //            Cbx01.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                   Txt01.setText(str);
                   return;
                }
            }
        }
            }
      });


      try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","root");
        TmpSqlStmnt=con.createStatement();
        TmpSqlRs=TmpSqlStmnt.executeQuery ("SELECT CateId,CateName FROM Cust_Masterrecord ORDER BY CateName");
        System.out.println("DB Connected");
        Cbx01.removeAllItems();
        TmpSqlRs.first();
           if (Cbx01.getItemCount() == 0)
           {

               //Cbx01.addItem("");
             do
              {
               // String s= TmpSqlRs.getString("CateName");
                Cbx01.addItem(TmpSqlRs.getString("CateName"));
                CateId=TmpSqlRs.getInt("CateId");
                v.add(CateId);
                // s.valueOf(CateId);
                // System.out.println(s.valueOf(CateId));
                // System.out.println(CateId);
                // for(int i=0;i<CateName.length;i++){
                v1.addElement(TmpSqlRs.getString("CateName"));
                 //}
                  Cbx01.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                                     if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

                                         //Cbx01.getItemCount();
                                         //System.out.println(Cbx01.getItemCount());
                                         //Cbx01.getSelectedItem();
                                         //System.out.println(Cbx01.getSelectedItem());

                                         Cbx01.getSelectedIndex();
                                        //System.out.println( Cbx01.getSelectedIndex());
                                        Lbl01.setText(v.get( Cbx01.getSelectedIndex()).toString());
                                      //System.out.println(v.get( Cbx01.getSelectedIndex()).toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            });

       }while(TmpSqlRs.next());
     }else{Cbx01.addItem("Records Not Available");}
   }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
  }


    }

private boolean hide_flag = false;
       private void setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel mdl, String str) {
        Cbx01.setModel(mdl);
        //Cbx01.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        Txt01.setText(str);
    }
private static DefaultComboBoxModel getSuggestedModel(java.util.List<String> list, String text) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel m = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        for(String s: list) {
            if(s.startsWith(text)) m.addElement(s);
        }
        return m;
    }




    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Cbx01 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        Lbl01 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Cbx01.setEditable(true);
        Cbx01.addPopupMenuListener(new javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener() {
            public void popupMenuCanceled(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
            }
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
                Cbx01PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(evt);
            }
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
                Cbx01PopupMenuWillBecomeVisible(evt);
            }
        });
        Cbx01.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                Cbx01ComponentMoved(evt);
            }
        });
        Cbx01.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                Cbx01ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                .addComponent(Cbx01, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addComponent(Lbl01, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 122, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(103, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(110, 110, 110)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Cbx01, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(Lbl01, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(170, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void Cbx01ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                       
//Lbl01.setText(v.get( Cbx01.getSelectedIndex()).toString());        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void Cbx01ComponentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                     
//Lbl01.setText(v.get( Cbx01.getSelectedIndex()).toString());        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void Cbx01PopupMenuWillBecomeVisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                 
    //   Lbl01.setText(v.get( Cbx01.getSelectedIndex()).toString()); // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                

    private void Cbx01PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                   
      // Lbl01.setText(v.get( Cbx01.getSelectedIndex()).toString()); // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                  

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               comboauto Tmpobj1= new comboauto();
               Tmpobj1.AutoSuggest();
               Tmpobj1.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox Cbx01;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Lbl01;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: forgot to clear `v` and `v1` before entering the loop?

Comment: Seems like you just need the name...String x = JComboBox.getSelectedItem();  Then poll the database for the ID if that's what you need.  OR, create an array with IDs indexed in the same way as the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

You can add objects to the combo box instead of adding strings. The object can contain both name and id, make sure that it has toString method that returns the name. Then you can get back the selected object by calling getSelectedItem on the combo box.

Comment: how to create object contain the name and id?

Comment: It is something like this:

public class MenuItemData{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   ... (get/set methods)
   public String toString(){ return this.name;}
}

Answer (score 0):

Replace `do while` (`while(TmpSqlRs.next());`) with `while` and check if output is coming properly or not...

Comment: No If I using the While condition the output is not come properly

Comment: what is not coming properly??

Comment: I think you are getting A ID in B as when `do` is executing for B, it had list of `A` too...

Comment: the same problem occurs again

Comment: well use 'Cbx01.removeAllItems();' inside `do` and check... I think this will solve the problem...

Comment: also in `TmpSqlRs=TmpSqlStmnt.executeQuery ("SELECT CateId,CateName FROM Cust_Masterrecord ORDER BY CateName");` I don't see any `WHERE` clause... I think your statement should be `TmpSqlRs=TmpSqlStmnt.executeQuery ("SELECT CateId,CateName FROM Cust_Masterrecord ORDER BY CateName WHERE CateName LIKE '%A'");` (considering you are searching for `A`

Comment: is your query is main problem? because you are not using `WHERE` clause... I don't have Java/ SQL here....

Comment: I think doing two step will solve your problem `1. Add WHERE Clause`, `2. take Cbx01.removeAllItems(); inside do loop` and use `WHILE` loop... do not USE `do while`

Comment: my problem is not getting name from database.the id will select based on the combobox list index.cbx01.getselectedIndex();

Comment: Still I have got the same problem..what is the another way instead of getselectedindex();